# Array Data in laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel

My array is :

```
 $firstData=array (
              '000' => 
              array (
                '000' => 
                array (
                  0 => '{"code":"11101000000","postal":"3310000","prefecture_kana":""}',
                ),
              ),
           )
```

i want to get postal's value in this array.Could you help me how to get postal value 3310000 .Thank for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a very basic PHP technique. You can get a value by key ex: $value = $arr['key'].

Let's try

```
$jsonString = $firstData['000']['000'][0];
$array_from_json = json_decode($jsonString , true);
echo( $array_from_json['postal']);
```

**Explanation**

Firstly, you should get a JSON string first

```
$jsonString = $firstData['000']['000'][0];
```

> $jsonString: '{"code":"11101000000","postal":"3310000","prefecture_kana":""}'

Then, we will parse this JSON string to array by using json_decode:

```
$array_from_json = json_decode($jsonString , true);
```

> $array_from_json: ["code"=>"11101000000","postal"=>"3310000","prefecture_kana"=>""]

Finally, get value in this array by a key "postal"

```
$postal = $array_from_json['postal'];
```

> $postal: 3310000

Comment: I try this 
**echo $firstData['postal'];**

and it works very well

Comment: You can copy my edited code and run on this website for checking http://www.writephponline.com/

Comment: $firstData=array (
  '000' => 
  array (
    '000' => 
    array (
      0 => '{"code":"11000000000","postal":"3456677","prefecture_kana":"","add_1_kana":"","add_2_kana":"","add_3_kana":"","prefecture":"埼玉県","add_1":"","add_2":"","add_3":""}',
    ),
  ),
);
echo( $firstData['postal']); i try this code on this site. but result is not out :'(

Comment: This given input is not similar to the original input. For this input, you should try **echo( json_decode($firstData['000']['000'][0], true)['postal']);**

Comment: I have edited my answer to make it suitable for you question. Please check it. If it can help you please do not forget to mark my answer as an answer to this question

Comment: thanks for your answer. i get it very well . but my array is dynamic.

Comment: Can you give me some sample?

Answer (score 0):

I think $firstData['postal] @@